# No current context. NDB calls must be made in context established by google.cloud.ndb.Client.context

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, migration, google-cloud-datastore

I have an appengine app that works with python2.7 and I want to migrate to python3.9. I started by making call to google ndb cloud inside my appengine app. I am using python3.9 and django as a web framwork.
This is my code:

```
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect
from google.cloud import  ndb


class Book(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()

client = ndb.Client()


def get_books():
    with client.context():
        books = Book.query()
        return books

def main(request):
    return HttpResponse(get_books())
```

And this is the traceback

```
File "/Users/hizan/Desktop/venvdjango/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/ndb/query.py" in wrapper
  1213.         context = context_module.get_context()

File "/Users/hizan/Desktop/venvdjango/lib/python3.9/site-packages/google/cloud/ndb/context.py" in get_context
  118.         raise exceptions.ContextError()

Exception Type: ContextError at /
Exception Value: No current context. NDB calls must be made in context established by google.cloud.ndb.Client.context.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of defining a context in each function/method where you're using NDB, you should create a middleware so that the context is automatically taken care of.

See [example](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/migration-center/standard/python/migrate-to-cloud-ndb#using_a_runtime_context_with_django) from Google for Django